# Magento (PHP): Add Product invisble to Cart

Tags: php, events, magento, observer-pattern, shopping-cart

I am looking for a way adding a product to cart without display it.

Example:

New customer order -> welcome letter in the cart, but the customer doesnt see it.

The added product cost always 0 €, so it never changed the shopping cart total.

The solution should be changed as few as possible.

Any idea?

Thank you!

(Sorry for my very bad english...)

Answer (score 3):

I would say to change the formulation a bit and add it to the order just before the order is saved. While the quote is being converted into an order (`sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` is one good event here, but there are others), add the product to the order.

This way, you don't have to hack around trying to hide items in the cart, and the effect is the same.

Comment: I agree this is the way to go here.  Do a logic check before it gets sent to the ERP system and add it there.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Define a new product type that extends the Virtual product type in Magento, and then use a custom Item Renderer for Checkout and Cart that doesn't output any html.  Here's a useful [tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-a-new-product-type-in-magento/) for that process.
2. Define a new boolean product attribute called "cart_visibility" or something like that, override `DOCROOT\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml` in your own theme and test for that value before outputting the item's attributes e.g. on line 28:

   `<?php if($_item->getCartVisibility(){ ?>`

Don't forget to close the brace at the end of the file obviously.

Comment: Considering this a little further, wouldn't he also have to modify the "no items in cart" logic? And the "X items in cart" global block? The original idea seems worse and worse the more I think about it.

Comment: @Joseph, you're right, the Observer on checkout completion is the best option. There's no value in having it in the cart before that, only complexity.

Answer (score 0):

if it's 0 then why add it to the cart just add it as a message to cart page by adding it to cart template or injecting your own block to this template

Comment: Because the added product must be sent to the erp and the customer is not supposed to know that he gets an extra "product".